# powershell xml xpath

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

In Powershell,
suppose I have the following xml:

```
  <Users>
    <User Name="Foo">
      <Friends>
        <Friend Name="Bar"/>
      </Friends>
    </User>
    <User Name="Foo2" />
    <User Name="Foo3">
      <Friends>
        <Friend Name="Bar"/>
      </Friends>
    </User>
  </Users>
```

How can I get all the users that have a "Bar" as a friend?
(In this example it would be Foo,Foo3).

Should I use xpath?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have a preference for using XPath these days. I've run into issues using PowerShell's xml adapter that are annoying like the name collision on `item`:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
  <Users> 
    <User Name="Foo"> 
      <Friends> 
        <Friend Name="Bar"/> 
      </Friends> 
    </User> 
    <User Name="Foo2" /> 
    <User Name="Foo3"> 
      <Friends> 
        <Friend Name="Bar"/> 
      </Friends> 
    </User> 
  </Users> 
'@

Select-Xml '//User[contains(Friends/Friend/@Name, "Bar")]' $xml |%{$_.Node.Name}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case I would use XPath as well. @TomWij provided the correct xpath.

In case that the xpath expression would be too complicated, I would for sure used the 'classic' approach.

```
$x.Users.User | ? { $_.Friends.Friend.Name -eq 'Bar' }
```

(in this case if you don't have script mode on, it doesn't matter that there is no `Friends` element. `$_.Friends` will return `$null` and `$null.Friend` returns `$null` as well and so on. So finally `$null -eq 'Bar'` returns false and the element is removed by Where-Object)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, XPath would be sufficient for that!

Check [Powershell to test your XPath](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Powershell_to_test_your_XPath.aspx) to see how it can be done.

Comment: /Users/User[contains(./Friends/Friend/@Name, "Bar")]

Comment: Please provide better link. This article doesn't use new cmdlet `Select-Xml` from V2. It is much more handy: `Select-Xml -xml $xml -xpath '/Users/User[contains(./Friends/Friend/@Name, "Bar")]'  | select -exp node`

Comment: I'm not able to edit my comment any more, so here is a link to Jaykul's post: http://huddledmasses.org/xpath-and-namespaces-in-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the other answers are perfectly acceptable, I personally prefer to do it using [`SelectNodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes).

Given the question XML in a variable `$xml`, the following will return an array.

```
$names = $xml.SelectNodes("//User[contains(Friends/Friend/@Name, 'Bar')]/@Name")
```

The `$names` variable is an `XPathNodeList` which is derived from [`XmlNodeList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist) and will output the following.

```
#text
-----
Foo
Foo3
```

If you want to grab the values, you can either iterate or grab by index. For example, `$names[1].Value` will produce `Foo3`.